# UIPickerView programmatic example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

How do I programmatically setup up the UIPickerView in a view without using Interface Builder?  Also having trouble understanding how to work with the delegate portions of the UIPickerView.

Comment: Here is a well documented and comprehensive example that works in iOS 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047257/3634990

Answer (score 29):

To add UIPickerView programmatically:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pV didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 1)
        selectedRowPicker1 = row;
    else if(component == 2)
        selectedRowPicker2 = row;
    else
        selectedRowPicker3 = row;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{ 
    if(component == 1)
        return [list1 count];
    else if(component == 2)
        return [list2 count];
    else
        return [list3 count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 1)
        val1 = [list1 objectAtIndex:row];
    else if(component == 2)
        val2 = [list2 objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        val3 = [list3 objectAtIndex:row];

    return strTemp;
}
```

Comment: How do I add 3 lists of different objects to 3 components in the picker? How do I retrieve each item selected per component?  thanks

Comment: I gave you a point because it add some more info to the other guys link.... thanks

Answer (score 17):

**This will not work in iOS 8**

Create **UIPickerView** programmatically with **DataSource**

.h file

```
@interface PickerViewTestAppViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
     UIActionSheet *pickerViewPopup;
     UIPickerView *categoryPickerView;
     UIPickerView *pickerView;
     NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet *pickerViewPopup;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *categoryPickerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataArray;

@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation PickerViewTestAppViewController

@synthesize pickerViewPopup,categoryPickerView;
@synthesize dataArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 // Init the data array.
 dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 // Add some data for demo purposes.
 [dataArray addObject:@"One"];
 [dataArray addObject:@"Two"];
 [dataArray addObject:@"Three"];
 [dataArray addObject:@"Four"];
 [dataArray addObject:@"Five"];

 pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

 categoryPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];

[categoryPickerView setDataSource: self];
[categoryPickerView setDelegate: self];
categoryPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(categoryDoneButtonPressed)];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(categoryCancelButtonPressed)];

    [pickerToolbar setItems:@[cancelBtn, flexSpace, doneBtn] animated:YES];

    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:categoryPickerView];
    [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];
    [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
// Handle the selection

NSLog(@"%@",[dataArray objectAtIndex:row]);       
selectedCategory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataArray objectAtIndex:row]];
}
// tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [dataArray count];
}

// tell the picker how many components it will have
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

// tell the picker the title for a given component
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [dataArray objectAtIndex: row];

}

// tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int sectionWidth = 300;

    return sectionWidth;
}

-(void)categoryDoneButtonPressed{
categoryLable.text = selectedCategory;
[pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}

-(void)categoryCancelButtonPressed{
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}
```

Ref: http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.in/2011/04/uipickerview-add-it-programmatically_04.html

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSInteger selectCourse=[_coursePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSInteger selectSem=[_coursePicker selectedRowInComponent:1];
    NSString *whatCourse=[Course objectAtIndex:selectCourse];
    NSString *whatSem=[Sem objectAtIndex:selectSem];

    NSString *courses=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Course : %@ - %@",whatCourse,whatSem];

    [self.selectedCours setTitle:courses forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the class i have created recently. Its in swift 4.1.2.
Just write one line and you picker will be on display.

```
import UIKit
class CustomPickerView:NSObject,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource{


    //Theme colors
    var itemTextColor = UIColor.black
    var backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    var toolBarColor = UIColor.blue
    var font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    private static var shared:CustomPickerView!
    var bottomAnchorOfPickerView:NSLayoutConstraint!
    var heightOfPickerView:CGFloat = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 160 : 120
    var heightOfToolbar:CGFloat = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 50 : 40

    var dataSource:(items:[String]?,itemIds:[String]?)

    typealias CompletionBlock = (_ item:String?,_ id:String?) -> Void
    var didSelectCompletion:CompletionBlock?
    var doneBottonCompletion:CompletionBlock?
    var cancelBottonCompletion:CompletionBlock?


    lazy var pickerView:UIPickerView={
        let pv = UIPickerView()
        pv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pv.delegate = self
        pv.dataSource = self
        pv.showsSelectionIndicator = true
        pv.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
        return pv
    }()

    lazy var disablerView:UIView={
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.alpha = 0
        return view
    }()

    lazy var tooBar:UIView={
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = self.toolBarColor
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(buttonDone)
        buttonDone.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        buttonDone.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        buttonDone.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        buttonDone.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 65).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(buttonCancel)
        buttonCancel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        buttonCancel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        buttonCancel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        buttonCancel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 65).isActive = true

        return view
    }()


    lazy var buttonDone:UIButton={
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = self.itemTextColor
        button.titleLabel?.font = self.font
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonDoneClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    lazy var buttonCancel:UIButton={
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = self.itemTextColor
        button.titleLabel?.font = self.font
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonCancelClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()


    static func show(items:[String],itemIds:[String]? = nil,selectedValue:String? = nil,doneBottonCompletion:CompletionBlock?,didSelectCompletion:CompletionBlock?,cancelBottonCompletion:CompletionBlock?){

        if CustomPickerView.shared == nil{
            shared = CustomPickerView()
        }else{
            return
        }

        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,let keyWindow = appDelegate.window {

            shared.cancelBottonCompletion = cancelBottonCompletion
            shared.didSelectCompletion = didSelectCompletion
            shared.doneBottonCompletion = doneBottonCompletion
            shared.dataSource.items = items

            if let idsVal = itemIds,items.count == idsVal.count{ //ids can not be less or more than items
                shared?.dataSource.itemIds  = itemIds
            }

            shared?.heightOfPickerView += shared.heightOfToolbar

            keyWindow.addSubview(shared.disablerView)
            shared.disablerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyWindow.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            shared.disablerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyWindow.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            shared.disablerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyWindow.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            shared.disablerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyWindow.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


            shared.disablerView.addSubview(shared.pickerView)
            shared.pickerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shared.disablerView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            shared.pickerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shared.disablerView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            shared.pickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: shared.heightOfPickerView).isActive = true
            shared.bottomAnchorOfPickerView = shared.pickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shared.disablerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
            shared.bottomAnchorOfPickerView.isActive = true


            shared.disablerView.addSubview(shared.tooBar)
            shared.tooBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: shared.heightOfToolbar).isActive = true
            shared.tooBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shared.disablerView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            shared.tooBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shared.disablerView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            shared.tooBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shared.pickerView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

            keyWindow.layoutIfNeeded()


            if let selectedVal = selectedValue{
                for (index,itemName) in items.enumerated(){
                    if itemName.lowercased() == selectedVal.lowercased(){
                        shared.pickerView.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }

            shared.bottomAnchorOfPickerView.constant = -shared.heightOfPickerView

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                keyWindow.layoutIfNeeded()
                shared.disablerView.alpha = 1
            }) { (bool) in  }

        }
    }


    //MARK: Picker datasource delegates
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = dataSource.items?.count{
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }



    //MARK: Picker delegates
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{
        if let names = dataSource.items{
            return names[row]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        if let names = dataSource.items{
            let item = names[row]
            return NSAttributedString(string: item, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : itemTextColor,NSAttributedStringKey.font : font])
        }
        return nil
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        var itemName:String?
        var id:String?

        if let names = dataSource.items{
            itemName = names[row]
        }
        if let ids = dataSource.itemIds{
            id = ids[row]
        }
        self.didSelectCompletion?(itemName, id)
    }



    @objc func buttonDoneClicked(){
        self.hidePicker(handler: doneBottonCompletion)
    }

    @objc func buttonCancelClicked(){

        self.hidePicker(handler: cancelBottonCompletion)
    }

    func hidePicker(handler:CompletionBlock?){
        var itemName:String?
        var id:String?
        let row = self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        if let names = dataSource.items{
            itemName = names[row]
        }
        if let ids = dataSource.itemIds{
            id = ids[row]
        }
        handler?(itemName, id)

        bottomAnchorOfPickerView.constant = self.heightOfPickerView
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.disablerView.window!.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.disablerView.alpha = 0
        }) { (bool) in
            self.disablerView.removeFromSuperview()
            CustomPickerView.shared = nil
        }
    }

}
```

You can use it anywhere, see example below.

```
 CustomPickerView.show(items: ["item1","item2","item3"],itemIds: ["id1","id2","id3"],selectedValue:"item3", doneBottonCompletion: { (item, index) in
            print("done",item,index)
        }, didSelectCompletion: { (item, index) in
            print("selection",item,index)
        }) { (item, index) in
            print("cancelled",item,index)
        }
```

Comment: To download file click this link : https://github.com/indrajitv/Custompickerview/blob/master/CustomPickerView.swift