# UIPickerView cannot select second component

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with two components but for whatever reason I can only do selections on the first but not second component. I followed very closely the code from [UIPickerView programatic example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636237/uipickerview-programatic-example). I didn't make any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the dataSource, delegate and picker "Outlets" from the nib file Connection inspector to the file owner?

It could be the reason that connections have not been set up properly. See below:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: You can simply connect the outlets in your nib(.xib) file without writing a separate code for this. But yes you can do the same by writing codes as well but writing code would be a tough solution and making connections on the nib file is the easiest one.