# pickerview is not showing the data stored in array

Tags: ios7, xcode5

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
    int selectedTextfieldValue;
   NSArray *namesArray , *genderArray, *ageArray;
   UIToolbar *pickerToolbar;

 }
  @end

 @implementation ViewController
@synthesize myPickerView;

 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
  namesArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil];
  genderArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"M",@"F", nil];
  ageArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"26",@"25", nil];
  selectedTextfieldValue=0;

  }



  -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
       if (textField==_text1)
     {
        _text1.delegate=self;
    }
 else
  if(textField==_text2)
{
    _text2.delegate=self;
 }
   else
      {
        _text3.delegate=self;
      }

      NSLog(@"%d",textField.tag);
     selectedTextfieldValue=(int)textField.tag;
       NSLog(@"%d",selectedTextfieldValue);
     // call picker here according to textfield tag you can set text to textfiled
      [self popoverWithInformation];
      }

      -(void)popoverWithInformation
         {
         pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 44)];
        pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
         [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
         NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


          UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(pickerCancel:)];
   [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];
```

/* UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
       [barItems addObject:flexSpace];*/

```
         UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDone:)];
       [barItems addObject:doneBtn];



[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];


    myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    CGRect pickerRect = myPickerView.bounds;
      myPickerView.bounds = pickerRect;
    myPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216);

     UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 300)];
     popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     [popoverView addSubview:myPickerView];

      [popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
     [self.view addSubview:popoverView];
 }

   // tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
  -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:       (NSInteger)component
   {
      int count = 0;

       switch (selectedTextfieldValue)
     {
        case 1:
            count =namesArray.count;
             NSLog(@"%d",count);
              break;
          case 2:
               count =genderArray.count;
             NSLog(@"%d",count);

               break;
            case 3:
               count =ageArray.count;
        NSLog(@"%d",count);

        break;
    default:
           NSLog(@"default in  count");
        break;
    }

     return count;
  }

    // tell the picker how many components it will have
       -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
      return 1;
     }

       // tell the picker the title for a given component
     -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row  forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

       NSString *title;

      switch (selectedTextfieldValue) {
        case 1:
        title =namesArray[row];
        break;
        case 2:
        title =genderArray[row];
        break;
         case 3:
        title =ageArray[row];
        break;  
         default:
        NSLog(@"default");
        break;
}


 return title;
```

}

```
 // tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
  -(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component       {
    int sectionWidth = 300;

   return sectionWidth;
}

 -(void)pickerDone:(id)sender
     {

        NSLog(@"Done Clicked");
         NSLog(@"Done Clicked%d",selectedTextfieldValue);
        myPickerView.hidden=YES;
        pickerToolbar.hidden=YES;

    }

  -(void)pickerCancel:(id)sender
    {

      NSLog(@"cancel");
      myPickerView.hidden=YES;
      pickerToolbar.hidden=YES;
   }
  @end
```

I want to display the values of array in picker view and for that I take 3 arrays and 3 textfield but picker view not showing the data.
any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please help any one..its very important as i have to stored the values fetched from webservices in the array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this you don't need to make PickerView every time. Make first time pickerview and reload components every time

```
 -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
   if (textField==_text1)
 {
    _text1.delegate=self;
 } else if(textField==_text2) {
     _text2.delegate=self;
 } else {
    _text3.delegate=self;
  }
 selectedTextfieldValue=(int)textField.tag;
 [myPickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

May be it's help full other wise  visit here  [UIPickerView programatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636237/uipickerview-programatic-example)  & [UIPickerView Tutorial](http://www.developersalmanac.com/uipickerview-tutorial/)