# UIPickerview data to core

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I am a rookie programmer, so please forgive the simple nature of this question.

I have created a picker view with 2 separate columns, and I'm trying to figure out how I export the users choices.  I'd like to put the choices in the core functionality but I have no idea what my next steps should be.

Does anyone have a suggestion?  Or perhaps a tutorial link that I can review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for following method:
[pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:)

You can use above method to determine what component was chosen (column in your case) and what row in that component (column). 
All you need to do is implement this method in the delegate object (You need to 'tell' the UIpickerView's object what is its delegate - do You know how to do this?).

[Here - iOS7 UIPickerView Example and Tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/) is a very good tutorial to implement UIpickerView in your app. Step by step. Just as You need:)

You can check also this similar question: [UIPickerView programatic example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636237/uipickerview-programatic-example)